# repeating html bootstrap code with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

is there any way to repeat the panel of bootstrap with different title and different content using jquery.I just want to repeat the panel of bootstrap every time with different title and different content or body.As i am trying with API http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts using $.ajax().I want to get the title and body from that API.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `$.ajax()` you can do it like this:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      $('.panel').append("<div class='panel-heading'>" + value.title + "</div><div class='panel-body'>" + value.body + "</div>")
        //console.log("TITLE: " + index + " "  + value.title);
        //console.log("BODY: " + index + " "  + value.body); 
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-primary">

</div>
```

You can also use `$.getJSON()`:

```js
$.getJSON("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    $('.panel').append("<div class='panel-heading'>" + value.title + "</div><div class='panel-body'>" + value.body + "</div>")
      //console.log("TITLE: " + index + " "  + value.title);
      //console.log("BODY: " + index + " "  + value.body); 
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-primary">

</div>
```